# Creating new dataset based on multiple observations from a variable

Tags: r

I am new to R and am having issues figuring out how to create a new dataset from 2 already existing datasets that I have.

I have two datasets that look like this, with different/identical MRNs

1. MRN  Age Status
2. 222  50  likely
3. 345  64  likely
4. 555  75  unknown
5. 888  56  likely
6. 675  52  unknown

Second Dataset

1. MRN  Age Status
2. 222  50  likely
3. 446  35  unknown
4. 555  75  unknown
5. 888  56  likely
6. 678  48  unknown

I wanted to find the identical MRN's that matched up between both datasets. So I used:

MatchedMRN <- intersect(Tissue$MRN, ctDNA$MRN)

but now I would like to create a new dataset with the matched MRN values, but also with all the other variable/columns in the original 2 datasets that go along with those MRN values. Is there anyway to do this in R?

Thank you!

Comment: An inner join should do it. `merge(Tissue, ctDNA)`.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [How to merge (join) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this type of issue using joins, from the dplyr package. Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(index = c("1", "2", "3"), age= c(20,44,32))

df2 <- data.frame(index = c("1", "2", "4"), sex=c("M", "M", "F"))

df1and2 <-full_join(df1, df2, by="index")
```

With this full join, you match the values in df1 with values in df2 based on index, which we use as a "primary key". We get a data frame with the columns age, index and sex. Where a key is only present in one data frame, you will have NA values for the columns coming from the other data frame.